# What's the [code] for Tag Cleanup?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

Stumbled across another one... The [code](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/code) tag. Again, who is an expert on everything that a "code" could encompass? Too meta, too broad... Get rid of it